# java - using methods to add two numbers

Tags: java

Building a simple program that does addition problems using methods, static variables and methods, and final variables. I have started the program with the following code below yet I am running into 4 errors with what I have. I have included all the errors that I am getting along with my .java file.

The goal is to try to get the output 2 numbers for the user to add together and to tell if it is true or false.

**Error in Command Prompt:**

```
CAI.java:43: error: '.class' expected
                int max = 50; int min = 1;
                    ^
CAI.java:43: error: illegal start of expression
                int max = 50; int min = 1;
                        ^
CAI.java:43: error: ';' expected
                int max = 50; int min = 1;
                         ^
CAI.java:44: error: not a statement
                rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                                              ^
4 errors
```

**CAI.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class CAI
{
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    static int addition;

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] arguments)
    {
        //declare variables
        String name;
        int addition;
        int subtraction;
        int multiplication;
        //boolean = true;

        //welcome the user
        System.out.println("Welcome to Computer Assisted Instruction");

        //get the user's name
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        name = input.next();

        System.out.printf("Hi %s. Let's practice addition!", name);
    }   


    private static boolean addition(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return (num1+num2)
        //generate double digit numbers positive and negative
        int max = 50; int min = 1;
        rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        //Addition
        System.out.printf("What is %d + %d? ", a,b);
        addition = input.nextInt();
    }



}
```

Comment: return (num1+num2) is the first line of your method. a return directly terminates the method flow and everything afterwards is dead code

Comment: `return (num1+num2)` is the culprit

Comment: remove `return (num1+num2)` as the first line

Comment: Your declarations come after a return statement. How do you expect them to ever execute? Next, your return statement doesn't end with a `;` - that's why you're getting the errors...

Comment: ***What*** are you doing? What is `return (num1+num2)` supposed to do? You are missing a `;`, you are putting code after the `return` and you are returning an incorrect type

Comment: also `rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;` as a single statement really doesn´t do anything usefull as you never use the return value of it, also what´s `a` and `b`?

Comment: Please do not perform major changes in the code of your question, if you feel like you need to add new code in a new section underneath the original one, but leave the original one in place.

Answer (score 0):

all the code after the `return (num1+num2)` statement is non reachable code...

furthermore that statement is missing a semicolon which is the reason of the msg

> error: '.class' expected

after adding the semicolon a non reachable code error will arise

do instead:

```
  int max = 50; int min = 1;
  rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
  //Addition
  System.out.printf("What is %d + %d? ", a,b);
  addition = input.nextInt();
  return (num1+num2);
```

Edit:

and if the method is declare to return a boolean you just can not return anoter type...

your method must be declared as :

```
private static int addition(int num1, int num2)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for explaining. However, this error is popping up `CAI.java:41: error: not a statement
                rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                                              ^
1 error`

Comment: I have it declared it the error is the `+` sign before the `min`

Answer (score 0):

To sum up what you did wrong:

- you `return` and then write your method logic, that does not work
- you are missing a `;` after the `return ...`
- your returned type does not match the declared return type
- `rand` is undefined or of the wrong type
- `a` and `b` are undefined
- the result of `rand.nextInt` is not assigned to anything
- your method `addition` has two parameters but you call it without any

Fixing all that ends up in something like:

```
private static boolean addition() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int max = 50; int min = 1;
    int a = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    int b = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    System.out.printf("What is %d + %d? ", a, b);

    int addition = input.nextInt();

    return (a + b) == addition;
}
```